# Method with pointer receiver vs value , conversion between value and pointer

Tags: go

As a part of learning about pointer vs value receivers I referred to:https://gobyexample.com/methods

```
// This `area` method has a _receiver type_ of `*rect`.
func (r *rect) area() int {
    return r.width * r.height
}

// Methods can be defined for either pointer or value
// receiver types. Here's an example of a value receiver.
func (r rect) perim() int {
    return 2*r.width + 2*r.height
}

func main() {
    r := rect{width: 10, height: 5}

    // Here we call the 2 methods defined for our struct.
    fmt.Println("area: ", r.area())
    fmt.Println("perim:", r.perim())

    // Go automatically handles conversion between values
    // and pointers for method calls. You may want to use
    // a pointer receiver type to avoid copying on method
    // calls or to allow the method to mutate the
    // receiving struct.
    rp := &r
    fmt.Println("area: ", rp.area())
    fmt.Println("perim:", rp.perim())
}
```

I dont understand -->

```
rp := &r   
rp is a pointer or address of r
```

why the result of:

```
rp.area()  is identical to r.area() 
rp.perim()  is identical to r.perim()
```

pointers : they are address of a var in memory.

The function area() requires a pointer receiver. so this is clear rp.area() (because rp is a pointer or address of r)

BUT why this r.area() ? r is NOT a pointer it is a value

Similarly perim requires a value we are using pointer as receiver?  rp.perim()

Also what does this mean:

You may want to use a pointer receiver type to avoid copying on method calls or to allow the method to mutate the receiving struct.

```
to avoid copying on method calls or to allow the method to mutate the receiving struct.
```

Comment: THx I do understand pointers (they are address of a var in memory). The function area requires a pointer receiver.  so this is clear rp.area() (because rp is a pointer or address of r) BUT why this  r.area() ? r is NOT a pointer it is a value Thats the essence of my Q

Comment: Note: I copied the above comments to an answer since they were kinda long. Answer: Go is automatically making a pointer to `r` when you call `r.area()`. I also found it weird that this is not a compile error when I first saw this, but that is how Go works.

Comment: Here is a Go Playground which shows what I mentioned: https://play.golang.org/p/RNDIMc-GQop (also posted on my answer below)

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/methods/4 ff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand what a pointer is in order to understand what's going on here. A pointer contains the address of another variable.

The two types of receiver are different in that one (pointer) expects an address and the other (value) expects not-an-address.

Now, to answer your first question: "Why are the results the same?"

First, `rp` is a pointer to `r`. Meaning what is contained in `rp` is the address of `r`. So both `r` and `rp` eventually refer to the same struct (`r` directly contains it and the address in `rp` points to it). So in the end it is the same struct.

Also, the reason `r` and `rp` can both be used with pointer and value receivers is this:
Go is automatically getting what's at the address contained in `rp` when calling `perim()` (which as a value receiver requires not-an-address) and it is automatically getting the address of `r` for passing when calling `area()` (which as a pointer receiver requires an address).

To answer your second question: "What does this mean ...?"

To understand this, you need to know that all functions in Go use pass-by-value. That means that when you pass a struct with many fields to a function, the entire struct with all its fields will be copied into a new variable to be used inside the function. However, if you pass a pointer (an address of the struct with many fields) only the address is copied into a variable to be used inside the function - which is a lot less copying.

Comment: ok this statement helps as it must be unique in Go right?  ""Also, the reason r and rp can both be used with pointer and value receivers is this: Go is automatically getting what's at the address contained in rp when calling perim() (which as a value receiver requires not-an-address) and it is automatically getting the address of r for passing when calling area() (which as a pointer receiver requires an address).""

Comment: Yep that's right. Here's a Go Playground showing the automatic pointer creation: https://play.golang.org/p/RNDIMc-GQop

Comment: Thanks by the way I have seen that playground that you just showed me. I couldn’t understand it before with respect to value and pointer receivers acting the same exact way but now I understand it is unique in Go. This was very helpful.  This whole idea of pointers and structures and addresses I learned it along time ago in C then I switch to python. In C above would not have been possible that’s where my confusion came.